# NSLayoutConstraint to hidden objects still overrides alternate constraint

Tags: ios6, nslayoutconstraint

I am just for the first time trying to use Autolayout in a nib. It would seem my case is textbook situation where the `NSLayoutConstraints` would be the perfect solution.

I have a `UITableviewCell` with `UILabel` and an image beside it. The image changes according to the properties of the underlaying data, it can change size and sometimes be hidden. My intent is for the label to keep a set distance from the image and to span the entire cell when the image is hidden.

I set constraints on the label accordingly:

- One constraint with trailing edge a set distance from the leading edge of the image, high priority but not required.
- One constraint with trailing edge a set distance from the superview edge, with much lower priority.
- Appropriate left and top restraints, no restraint for the width of the label.

The label remains shortened by the first constraint, even when the image is hidden. Is this expected behavior? I would ordinarily calculate and change the width of the label at runtime but this seems exactly the sort of situation that NSLayoutConstraints was meant for.

How do I get it to ignore the restraint to the image when the image is not visible?

Comment: I believe the 1st constraint still takes place because it has higher priority than 2nd constraint. You will need to remove the 1st constraint when the image is hidden.

Comment: I figure there is a programmatic solution, I find some other threads with possibilities. Before I commit there, I want to be sure I am not missing something simple. It seems this would be a simple case, for which NSLayoutConstraints would not need coding "help". Thank you for the suggestion, I am trying some of those options right now.

Comment: @verbumdei you got me on the right track. I added an outlet for the constraint to the image. I first tried changing the priority, that had no effect. I then, as you suggested, removed it and added it back as appropriate. Fairly simple. If you post as an answer, with a bit of detail how to do it, I will give you credit as accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the class reference of NSLayoutConstraint, changing the priority of a constraint is not allowed once the constraint is laid. And a higher priority constraint will always override the lower ones.

The constraint can be removed and added back. If the constraint is put through storyboard or IB, you can make an IBOutlet of NSLayoutConstraint and connect it.

If you use the Xcode feature that auto-generates the line of code for the IBOutlet, it will declare the IBOutlet as weak. You need to change it to strong if you are going to add back the constraint some time in future after you remove it. This is to avoid the constraint being released after it is removed.

Then you can remove the first constraint if the image is hidden, and the second constraint will take place.

```
[self.view removeConstraint:self.firstConstraint];
```

You might need to call the layoutIfNeeded after removing the constraint.

Comment: Nailed it. I didn't actually need to call setNeedsLayout, probably because I altered the constraints before changing the image properties. +1 for the weak/strong tip. I found that out the hard way.

Comment: @deandavids yeah, I also found it out the hard way last time. The constraint was not added back because it was nil. Just checked my code. I called layoutIfNeeded after modifying the constraints. Just updated my answer.

Comment: A little correction. Changing the priority of a constraint is allowed except when changing from NSLayoutPriorityRequired to something lower, or from any value to NSLayoutPriorityRequired.

Answer (score 5):

With ios 8, you can activate/deactivate a constraint (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/UIKit.html):

I would create 2 constraints, one with lower priority, and deactivate the higher priority one when hiding the view, and reactivating it when the view is visible again:

[self.firstConstraint setActive:NO];

Comment: Agreed. Actually there are a myriad of new ways of doing this now with class sizes and storyboards. Won't find much use for this routine going forward. plus 1 for the updated method.

Comment: what do we need for iOS 7?